# Java: Как работает InputStream и System.in.read();

Tags: java

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста, что происходит когда я запускаю такой код:

```
int z = System.in.read(); // ввожу 100
System.out.println(z); // выводит 49
System.out.println((char)z); // выводит 1
```

Не могу понять откуда взялось значение 49. Каким образом метод read() преобразовал 100 в 49? Объясните подробно пожалуйста.

Comment: Метод `read` считывает байт. В этом байте [код символа](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) '1' - 49.

Comment: Каким образом метод read из 100 получил 49?

Comment: Не из 100, а из "1".

Comment: @остапбендер "100" - это три символа "1", "0" и ещё один "0". Код символа 1 - это 49. Метод `read` считывает один байт, то есть только первый символ.

Comment: Почему из 1, если я ввёл 100?

Comment: Потому что метод read считывает только один символ. Вы можете ввести хоть 100500 символов, считан будет только один. И не путайте 1 (число) и "1" (текст, строка).

Answer (score 1):

Как уже писали выше, метод System.in.read() считывает лишь первый символ какой угодно строки и в переменную типа int кладёт значение символа согласно некоторой системе кодировки символов (например, ASCII). В данном случае считывается символ '1', [код которого](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) равен 49.